# Creating a dictionary with keys from a list and values as lists from another list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list

```
key_list = ['m.title', 'm.studio', 'm.gross', 'm.year']
cols = [
    ['Titanic', 'The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King', 'Toy Story 3'], 
    ['Par.', 'NL', 'BV'],
    ['2186.8', '1119.9', '1063.2'],
    ['1997', '2003', '2010']
]
```

I want to construct a dictionary table_dict whose keys are the elements of key_list, and values are respective sublists of cols.

My current code is as follows:

```
i = 0
for key in key_list:
    table_dict[key] = cols[i]
    i = i + 1

return table_dict
```

I can't seem to find an error, yet when I run it I get:

```
dict[key] = cols[i]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Please show us the complete stacktrace.

Comment: I suppose you initialized table_dict somewhere as table_dict = dict()?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply [zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) the keys and values and pass it to the `dict`. You can read more about constructing dictionaries [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)

```
print dict(zip(key_list, cols))
```

**Output**

```
{'m.gross': ['2186.8', '1119.9', '1063.2'], 'm.studio': ['Par.', 'NL', 'BV'], 'm.year': ['1997', '2003', '2010'], 'm.title': ['Titanic', 'The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King', 'Toy Story 3']}
```

Comment: Agreed, though I'd probably throw in an assert that len(key_list) == len(cols).

Answer (score 1):

```
key_list = ['m.title', 'm.studio', 'm.gross', 'm.year']
cols = [
['Titanic', 'The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King', 'Toy Story 3'], 
['Par.', 'NL', 'BV'],
['2186.8', '1119.9', '1063.2'],
['1997', '2003', '2010']]
for i in cols:
    print dict(zip(key_list, i))
```

**If You want OUTPUT like this**

```
{'m.gross': 'Toy Story 3', 'm.studio': 'The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King','m.title': 'Titanic'}{'m.gross': 'BV', 'm.studio': 'NL', 'm.title': 'Par.'}{'m.gross': '1063.2', 'm.studio': '1119.9', 'm.title': '2186.8'}{'m.gross': '2010', 'm.studio': '2003','m.title': '1997'}
```

Answer (score 0):

The example you provided works without an error. There might be another problem within your code. However, what the error message tells you is that,

The index i of list cols is out of bounds. Which means while iterating over the first list (which has 4 elements in it, so iterating 4 times) the other list cols does not have enough items - meaning less than 4 probably.

The work around this issue refer to the python docs [dict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)

```
table_dict = dict(zip(key_list, cols))
print table_dict
```

Output:

```
{'m.gross': ['2186.8', '1119.9', '1063.2'], 'm.studio': ['Par.', 'NL', 'BV'], 'm.year': ['1997', '2003', '2010'], 'm.title': ['Titanic', 'The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King', 'Toy Story 3']}
```