# Creating a Dictionary from a Key List and Item List Based on the Order of the Elements in the Item List

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

After Looking at this question I found it helpful to find out how to use unique lists as items and a singular list as the keys: [Creating a dictionary with keys from a list and values as lists from another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20344505/creating-a-dictionary-with-keys-from-a-list-and-values-as-lists-from-another-lis)
However, I have lists where the first, second, and other elements of the lists need to be associated with the key list in that order.

The problem is that I have tried the method described in that question, but it did not account for the order of the elements in each of the lists within the master list in ascribing the items to the keys of my dictionary.

```
key_list = ['m.title', 'm.studio', 'm.gross', 'm.year']
col = [['Titanic', '2186.8', 'Par.', '1997'], 
['The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King', '1119.9', 'NL', '2003']]
```

I want to have a dictionary where the items of the col lists are ascribed to the key_list based on the order that the elements appear in all of the lists and matched to the order of the elements in the key_list.

Desired Output: {m.title:['Titanic', 'The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King'], 'm.studio':['2186.8', '1119.9'], 'm.gross':['Par.', 'NL'], 'm.year':['1997', '2003']}

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: You tagged this with CSV, are you reading it in from a csv file?

Comment: I tagged it in with csv because yes, but also I am going export the dictionary to a csv file.

Comment: @U9-Forward I edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `dict(zip(...))`:

```
print([dict(zip(key_list,values)) for values in col])
```

**Edit:**

```
print({k:list(zip(*col))[i] for i,k in enumerate(key_list)})
```

Or @MarkMeyer's solution.

Comment: @DataScienceAcolyte Will do

Comment: @DataScienceAcolyte edited mine, but Mark's solution is pretty good too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you really need the lists or if you can use tuples. But if tuples are okay, this is very succinct with:

```
d = dict(zip(key_list, zip(*col)))
```

Result:

```
{'m.title': ('Titanic', 'The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King'),
 'm.studio': ('2186.8', '1119.9'),
 'm.gross': ('Par.', 'NL'),
 'm.year': ('1997', '2003')}
```

Answer (score 0):

The list of objects you want to create can be created with a Dict comprehension nested within a List comprehension:

```
[{key_list[idx]: val for idx, val in enumerate(row)} for row in col]
```

> [{'m.year': '1997', 'm.gross': 'Par.', 'm.title': 'Titanic', 'm.studio': '2186.8'}, {'m.year': '2003', 'm.gross': 'NL', 'm.title': 'The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King', 'm.studio': '1119.9'}]

**Edit**:

For a dict of `{ key: List }`:

```
dict(zip(key_list, [[row[idx] for row in col] for idx,_ in enumerate(key_list)]))
```

> {'m.year': ['1997', '2003'], 'm.gross': ['Par.', 'NL'], 'm.title': ['Titanic', 'The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King'], 'm.studio': ['2186.8', '1119.9']}

Comment: Thank you this is helpful, but to clarify my question I was actually looking for a singular dictionary. with both years as the items associated m.year etc. I will edit my question to clraify